# javascript object keys and value if value match then store

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key-value

I have an object and another is object list1 get from the query but I want to store Obj key value into the array.

```
var Obj = { 
  '1': 'Test 1',
  '2': 'Test 2',
  '3': 'Test 3',
  '4': 'Test 4',
  '5': 'Test 5'
}
```

I get data from a query that is an index value in data2 key  1,2,3,4 and 5 in an object 
query = 'select data1, data2, data3 from test';

```
list1 = [{
      data1: 123,
      data2: 4,
      data3: 'value3',
}]
```

I want an object output if data2 value.

```
list1 = [{
      data1: 123,
      data2: 'TEST 4',
      data3: 'value3',
}];
```

Comment: Umm. `list1` is not an array, it is an object ( see the data1: 123 where data1 is the key and 123 is the value ).

Edit: After your edit.
`list1` is now neither an object nor an array.
perhaps you were going for
```
list1 = [
    {data: 123},
    {data: 4},
    {data: 'value3'},
]
```
Now, list1 is an array of object.

Comment: if you get my question then answer please

Answer (score 0):

what is being done below is:
Traverse through the `list1` array. Since it's an array of objects, we traverse the objects and update the `item[iter]` if the `Obj[item[iter]]` is not `undefined`.

```
list1.forEach( item => {
  for (iter in item) {
    item[iter] = Obj[item[iter]] !== undefined ? Obj[item[iter]] : item[iter]
  }
})
```

The result is

```
[
  {
    "data1": 123,
    "data2": "Test 4",
    "data3": "value3"
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the desired result by using the `map` operator to transform your array of objects and by looking up for the `data2` attribute from the `Obj` object as

```js
var Obj = {
  '1': 'Test 1',
  '2': 'Test 2',
  '3': 'Test 3',
  '4': 'Test 4',
  '5': 'Test 5'
}

list1 = [{
  data1: 123,
  data2: 4,
  data3: 'value3',
}]


var finalList = list1.map(obj => ({
  data1: obj.data1,
  data2: Obj[obj.data2],
  data3: obj.data3
}));

console.log(finalList)
```